# Edit history doesn't show edited portion - bug?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, editing, redaction

I was trying to see what edit was made in this [particular answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/95658/17368) but the edit history doesn't show the edited portion. I thought maybe some extra spaces was wiped out but couldn't figure where was the extra spaces in the first place. Even if there was acres of spaces between the paragraphs, the final answer doesn't show any space. What happened here?

[image]

The main motivation is to see what was edited because the answer looks like advertisement to me.

Comment: I think you can flag answers like these if you think they are spam, and this looks a bit like spam to me. I personally would not object to deleting this example.

Comment: Clearly I was deleting some incriminating info about myself... More seriously, I'm afraid I don't remember this at all, so can't give any extra info beyond what the mods have said. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually something of a special case. It looks like the original answer had some sensitive information that could be seen in the edit history. It was removed in the edit and then shortly after also redacted from the original post. So since the edit only affected content that was later redacted, the diff between the edits is blank.

Note mods can redact only with approval from another mod and that once the redaction has gone through that content is no longer visible even to other mods (at least I haven't seen a way to actually view it, I just see an additional indicator in the edit history that it was redacted).

Answer (score 3):

What Tyberius wrote is correct.

Typically redacted information includes, but is not limited to, email and phone numbers.

Since redaction is one of those few processes that generally go by without anyone noticing, I'd like to add a few things though. The feature isn't that old (a couple of years maybe), before then, moderators had to raise tickets to remove such information.

There is a recommended practice (somewhere, I think and iirc) to first create a new edit entry and then remove the sensitive information from the past revision.

In most cases I dealt with I opted to radically edit the source post. Then I replaced the sensitive information with something like (redacted). I have not done it often, and it'll be a pain to find.
Doing it this way has the advantage that the sensitive information is not visible immediately anymore. Since it needs confirmation by a second moderator, it could be out in the open for a while.
Most of the times, however, the posts needing redaction are boarding towards spam.

There is, as stated before, not much information available anymore, but this could actually be our very first attempt at redaction.